# Python SGDregressor, different results of RMSLE

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to implement SDGregressor from scikit-learn for simple linear regression problem, but my code gives a different value of RMSLE each time?

I wonder why this is so?  Also, I'm wondering how to get the least value of the RMSLE?

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#load data
train = pd.read_csv('Train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('Test.csv')

#split data
x_train = train.GrLivArea[:1000].values.reshape(-1,1)
y_train = train.SalePrice[:1000].values.reshape(-1,1)

x_train_normal = np.log(x_train)
y_train_normal = np.log(y_train) #Normalization

x_test = train.GrLivArea[1000:].values.reshape(-1,1)
y_test = train.SalePrice[1000:].values.reshape(-1,1)

x_test_normal = np.log(x_test)
y_test_normal = np.log(y_test) # Normalization

y_test_transform = np.exp(y_test_normal)

Model = linear_model.SGDRegressor()
Model.n_iter = np.ceil(10**7 / len(y_train_normal))
Model.fit(x_train_normal,y_train_normal)

Sale_Prices_Predicted = Model.predict(x_test_normal)
Sale_Prices_Prediceted_Transform = np.exp(Sale_Prices_Predicted)

rmslee = rmsle(y_test_transform, Sale_Prices_Prediceted_Transform)
print("RMSLE: ", rmslee)
```

For example:

```
0.28153047299638045
0.28190513681658363
0.28207666380009233
0.28126007334118047
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple, the SGDRegessor is not initialized the same way each time. If you want to have reproducible results, you need to fix **the seed**.

Different random initialisations mead to slightly different results.
Very common situation in Machine Learning.

This behavior can appear for any kind of  model which is randomly initialized:

- Neural Networks
- Random Forests
- SVM
- etc.

Documentation SGDRegressor: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html

> random_state : int, RandomState instance or None, optional
>   (default=None)
>
> The seed of the pseudo random number generator to use when shuffling
>   the data. If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number
>   generator; If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number
>   generator; If None, the random number generator is the RandomState
>   instance used by np.random.

Comment: @DejanSamardžija And? How does that contradict the answer?

Comment: I set RandomState = 10 and result is: 0.28422149811336855
I set RandomState = 100 and result is: 0.2820012362843276
I set RandomState = 1000 and result is: 0.28134354551213864
I set RandomState = 10000 and result is: 0.2812534516886991
I set RandomState = 100000 and result is: 0.281257305557422
I set RandomState = 1000000 and result is: 0.281257305557422

But without this parameter I got even better results, round 0.2809...?

Comment: I'm just curious about this :)

Comment: @DejanSamardžija Read some *basic* tutorial about SGD (really... it's important)! Interpret the optimizer as stochastic-function. For each seed there is one path to some solution. What path is best is infeasible to reason about a-priori. And don't tune the seeding. Tune every other parameter you need to (or use another optimizer which has less variance / deterministic).

Comment: Hmm, i will.. Thank you!

Comment: Linear regression is actually a simple convex-optimization problem and we can approximate the global-optimum as accurate as we need in polynomial-time. **But** that does not mean that SGD does! SGD has hyper-parameters and only achieves convergence for some parameters (not easily set a-priori). SGD is popular, because it's fast, really fast. For smaller datasets, other methods are more *reliable* (and also available in sklearn).

Comment: I just started learning.. I'm trying to figure out what is gradient descent actually and how to implement full batch gradient descent algorithm and
stochastic gradient descent algorithm on LR.. Thank you for your advice